# matplotlib TclError on OS X

Tags: python, matplotlib, tcl

I'm trying matplotlib on a Mac machine and I can't generate any iterative plots with it. The UI is displayed without any plot on it and I see the following exception being raised:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 245, in resize
    self.show()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 249, in draw
    tkagg.blit(self._tkphoto, self.renderer._renderer, colormode=2)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 19, in blit
    tk.call("PyAggImagePhoto", photoimage, id(aggimage), colormode, id(bbox_array))
TclError
```

I have tried reinstalling Tcl/Tk but the result is still the same. Is there anything else I can try? This happens every time I try to generate an interactive plot, the static (png) ones are ok.

Comment: Ugh; it's not reporting what the exception on the Tcl side is.

Comment: I have zero experience with Tcl. Is there anyway to know what is the Tcl exception? Any log?

Comment: The trace will have been written to the Tcl global variable `errorInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this very same problem running it on Lion and python 2.7, but my problem turned to be very simple, or better yet, very stupid; I had installed numpy and matplotlib for Mac OS 10.3, so I installed them both for the correct version 10.6 and now everything is working. btw, official packages can be found on their respective sourceforge pages,

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and I found that it is because the mixed version of matplotlib and numpy, after I remove them completely, and reinstall them, everything becomes good.